# How to make a one dimensional array to display multiples of seven

Tags: c#, console-application

I am attempting to code a one dimensional array to display code allowing me to display multiples of seven, I'm not sure how to go through with this, thank you.

Comment: Why not a list of integer getting items on a foreach multiplying i * 7 ??

Comment: well... how far did you get? was there a particular place where you're stuck? this *sounds* like "do my homework for me", and that goes down *really, really badly* here

Comment: A array like [0, 7, 14, 21, 28]? You can do that with a single for loop.

Comment: Yeah, I know this is newbie stuff but the tutorial doesn't offer me a guide. I'm new to this I just wanted to knowhow I can gt it to display [7,14,21,28,35,42] after running as I haven't been shown how.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question. You can use generate multiples of 7 using Linq as follows.

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => x * 7).ToArray();
```

[Enumerable.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.7.2) allows you to generate a sequence of values in specified range (First parameter is the first number in sequence, the second parameter is number of items), while the Select statement (`x=>x*7, multiply each value in generated sequence with 7`) ensures you get the multiples of 7.

Complete Code:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => x * 7).ToArray();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: When I type @AnuViswan's answer it does not run the code even with System.Linq, what else to I include?

Comment: @DidacticBassoon What does it say?

Comment: The program [8728] consoleapp6.exe and has exited with code 0 (0x0) @AnuViswan

Comment: @DidacticBassoon What do you expect to happen? The message you just posted is not an error.

Comment: @DidacticBassoon I have posted the complete code for displaying the result. Probably you missed adding a ReadLine/ReadKey statement in the end and the application exited before you could view the result. Please check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Due to the vagueness of the question, my answer may not be applicable, but I will attempt to answer based on my assumption of what you are asking.

If you have an array of `int` and you want to multiply the values of the individual array objects, you would do something like this:

```
        int[] myArray= { 3,5,8};
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myArray[i]*7);
        }
        //outputs 21,35,56
```

If you want to multiply based on the index of the array object, you would do it like this:

```
        int[] myArray= { 3,5,8};
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i*7);
        }
        //outputs 0,7,14

        //or if you need to start with an index of 1 instead of 0
        int[] myArray= { 3,5,8};
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((i+1)*7);
        }
        //outputs 7,14,21
```

Anu Viswan also has a good answer, but depending on what it is you are trying to do, it may be better to rely on loops. Hope my answer helps.